# Hrtimers and clockid_t problems

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am working on a new linux scheduler, and I need hrtimers.
I read how to implement them, in:
http://lwn.net/Articles/167897/

I made a small program, to test these timers before using them, and I have some problems.

That small program is something like this:

```
#include "linux/ktime.h"
#include "linux/hrtimer.h"
#include "linux/timer.h"
#include "linux/tick.h"

static void funcion_timers(unsigned long data) {

    printk(" HOLA HA SALTADO EL TIMER y el dato es %lu \n", data);

}

int main () {

    ktime_t kt;
    int i;
    struct hrtimer my_timer;
    clockid_t reloj;
    enum hrtimer_mode mode;
    kt = ktime_set(0, 5000000);
    reloj=CLOCK_MONOTONIC;
    mode=HRTIMER_REL;

    printk("EMPIEZA EL PROGRAMA");

    hrtimer_init(&my_timer, reloj);

    my_timer.function=&funcion_timers;
    my_timer.data=3;

    hrtimer_start(&my_timer, kt, mode);

    for (i=0; i<10000; i++) { } //A kind of waste of time cause I had problem with sleep into the kernel
}
```

And when I compile I am told (I'm not copying from the shell because it is in Spanish xD):

- `HRTIMER_REL` was not been declared
- `hrtimer_init` needs more arguments
- In `my_timer.function=&funcion_timers;` I have an incompatible pointer type :S
- `struct hrtimer` doesn't have a member called `data`

Why does hrtimer_init need arguments? I thought it was defined as:

```
*void hrtimer_init(struct hrtimer *timer, clockid_t which_clock);*
```

In conclusion, I think I may have not understand how `clockid_t` works; how does it work?
I cannot find too much information about it on the Internet.

Thanks a lot, :D
Alberto

Comment: This tutorial is outdated. Many things have changed since then. For example [HRTIMER_REL](http://sourceware.org/ml/systemtap/2008-q1/msg00014.html)

Answer (score 2):

`int main()`? Are you trying to call kernel functions from user space?

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Banthar, the API for hrtimers has changed, and thus made quite a few of the examples in existence on the internet outdated. You can have a look at the current functions at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/hrtimer.h, and the commit messages usually (cross your fingers first though) give an idea of what has changed, why, and what you should do to make your code work.

From the above link:

`HRTIMER_REL` has been renamed to `HRTIMER_MODE_REL`

`hrtimer_init()` needs a mode parameter (in your case probably `HRTIMER_MODE_REL`)

The callback function needs to be of type: `enum hrtimer_restart (*function)(struct hrtimer *)`

The `data` member has been removed from `struct hrtimer`, as the timer itself is now passed to the callback function.